# Unable to set a refresh rate higher than 60Hz after installing nvidia driver

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, xorg, monitor, xrandr

- After fresh installing Ubuntu 20 everything works fine with a monitor (LG w2363d) at 120hz and 1920x1080 with nouveau driver(GTX 1060) and mobo(Sabertooth 990fx), except when I install any nvidia driver (tried 450, 455 beta, 440, 418, 390) my resolution sets to 1024x768 and refresh rate at 85Hz (1920x1080 not being available, the highest was 1600x1200 @ 60Hz)
- I would stick to nouveau driver if it wasn't for tensorflow so I do need it installed.
- I somehow managed to bring 1920x1080 as an available resolution but with a maximum of 60Hz.
- I tried the following to increase refresh rate to 120Hz:

1. `xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_120.00" 369.50  1920 2080 2288 2656  1080 1083 1088 1160 -hsync +vsync`,
    but when I apply
    `xrandr --addmode DVI-D-0 1920x1080_120.00`
    I get

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  41
  Current serial number in output stream:  42
```

A little further reading and I found out that xrandr wouldn't work whatsoever when an nvidia driver is installed and I should stick to modifying xorg file to force apply a refresh rate higher than the standard one.

2. Tried to generate a modeline, with -r, without r, different resolutions and refresh rates but no success 
   Tried to set HorizSync and VertRefresh from monitor website spec list 
   Tried different device and screen settings but none worked

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 450.80.02

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "GSM"
    ModelName      "W2363D"
    Option         "DPMS"
    Option         "PreferredMode" "1920x1080"
    Option         "TargetRefresh" "120"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 120.0
    Modeline       "1920x1080R"  285.25  1920 1968 2000 2080  1080 1083 1088 1144 +hsync -vsync
    Option         "PreferredMode" "1920x1080R"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    Option "ModeValidation" "DVI-D-0: AllowNonEdidModes"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DVI-D-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
#    Option         "ModeValidation" "NoVesaModes, NoXServerModes"
    Option         "ExactModeTimingsDVI" "True"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
        Modes       "1920x1080_119.98"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

3. Modified in monitors.xml the refresh rate still no change

```
<monitors version="2">
  <configuration>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>1</scale>
      <primary>yes</primary>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>DVI-D-1</connector>
          <vendor>GSM</vendor>
          <product>W2363D</product>
          <serial>0000000000</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>119.982177734375</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
  </configuration>
  <configuration>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>1</scale>
      <primary>yes</primary>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>DVI-D-0</connector>
          <vendor>unknown</vendor>
          <product>unknown</product>
          <serial>unknown</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>59.933879852294922</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
  </configuration>
</monitors>
```

4. In nvidia x server settings I get Acquire EDID greyed out, and connection is single link if I use an DVI-D cable:
   [Image - Nvidia x server settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyWeC.png)

5. By running `get-edid | parse-edid` I got the following:
   To note that with nouveau driver I get the same output so I don't think there is an issue if checksum failed

```
This is read-edid version 3.0.2. Prepare for some fun.
Attempting to use i2c interface
No EDID on bus 1
No EDID on bus 2
No EDID on bus 3
No EDID on bus 4
No EDID on bus 5
No EDID on bus 6
No EDID on bus 8
No EDID on bus 9
No EDID on bus 10
No EDID on bus 11
2 potential busses found: 0 7
Will scan through until the first EDID is found.
Pass a bus number as an option to this program to go only for that one.
Bus 0 doesn't really have an EDID...
256-byte EDID successfully retrieved from i2c bus 7
Looks like i2c was successful. Have a good day.
Checksum Correct

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "W2363D"
    ModelName "W2363D"
    VendorName "GSM"
    # Monitor Manufactured week 3 of 2011
    # EDID version 1.3
    # Digital Display
    DisplaySize 510 280
    Gamma 2.20
    Option "DPMS" "true"
    Horizsync 30-141
    VertRefresh 59-121
    # Maximum pixel clock is 300MHz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1280x1024, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1280x1024, 75Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1152x864, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1680x1050, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1280x960, 75Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1152x864, 75Hz

    #Extension block found. Parsing...
Extension block checksum failed
```

6. Other things  to mention:

- My motherboard has no secure boot option
- Running Ubuntu through dual boot, the connection to the monitor is through DVI-D cable, and in windows it works fine at 120Hz, as well as with nouveau driver in ubuntu.
- Another interesting thing is that with nouveau driver the connection in xrandr is made through DVI-D-1 while when i install the nvidia driver it changes to DVI-D-0. Also running `xrandr -s 0` works fine but when i try screen 1 or 2 or 3 instead of 0 it goes black
- In Ubuntu settings, in displays, I get Unknown display(except when using nouveau or if I use HDMI).
- When I tried installing older versions of nvidia driver, it said that a newer version was found and it installed all versions until the last one(eg. If I wanted 430, it installed 430, 440 and 450)
- Tried installing the driver through all means available.

I hope there are no details that I missed but I am at the end of my strengths in solving this issue. If someone has any clue on how to solve this issue it would be awesome. Thank you !

Comment: "In Ubuntu settings, in displays, I get Unknown display(except when using nouveau or if I use HDMI)." So does HDMI cable work? if so then why not switch to HDMI cable permanently

Comment: Because this monitor supports 120Hz only through DVI-D, not HDMI. I know I shouldn't be bothered to use it at 60Hz but if it works through nouveau with 120Hz it must work through nvidia as well. It's just maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: where are you getting that info? lg spec sheet does not state that dvi-d is the only way to get 120Hz at 1080p source (https://www.lg.com/uk/monitors/lg-W2363D-3d-lcd-monitor)

Comment: Indeed, there is no info stating that on their page, but if you check their manual it states that HDMI tops off at 60Hz while Digital(DVI) at 120Hz (https://www.manualslib.com/manual/243306/Lg-W2363d.html?page=23#manual)
Btw, I learned this not from the manual but the hard way, by buying cables.

Comment: indeed it does I have taken a closer look at your posted xorg I believe you need to edit the meta modes option from (Option         "metamodes" "DVI-D-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0") to (Option         "metamodes" "DVI-D-0: 1920x1080_120 +0+0") at least thats the way mine is but with 144 instead of 120

Comment: Unfortunately this option doesn't seem to change anything, but thank you !

Answer (score 0):

here is my xorg.conf located at /ect/x11 this may help you set yours up as I see many differences between yours and mine at the very least it can serve as a reference

## nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig

## nvidia-xconfig:  version 455.28

## nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings

## nvidia-settings:  version 440.82

## nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig

## nvidia-xconfig:  version 435.21

Section "ServerLayout"

```
Identifier     "Layout0"
Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
Option         "Xinerama" "0"
```

EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

```
# generated from default
Identifier     "Mouse0"
Driver         "mouse"
Option         "Protocol" "auto"
Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
```

EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

```
# generated from default
Identifier     "Keyboard0"
Driver         "kbd"
```

EndSection

Section "Monitor"

```
Identifier     "Monitor0"
VendorName     "Unknown"
ModelName      "Microstep MSI G241"
HorizSync       180.0 - 180.0
VertRefresh     48.0 - 144.0
Option         "DPMS"
```

EndSection

Section "Device"

```
Identifier     "Device0"
Driver         "nvidia"
VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1070"
Option         "Coolbits" "13"
```

EndSection

Section "Screen"

```
Identifier     "Screen0"
Device         "Device0"
Monitor        "Monitor0"
DefaultDepth    24
Option         "TripleBuffer" "On"
Option         "Stereo" "0"
Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-6"
Option         "metamodes" "DP-4: 1920x1080_144 +0+0 {AllowGSYNCCompatible=On}, HDMI-0: 1920x1080_60 +1920+0"
Option         "SLI" "Off"
Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
SubSection     "Display"
    Depth       24
EndSubSection
```

EndSection